# Overriding template not working in Magento 2

Tags: template, magento-2.1, overrides, phtml

I have following code

> etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="XYZ_Checkout" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 XYZ. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_item_price_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="XYZ_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="XYZ_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Itdeation\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer */

$_item = $block->getItem();
$product = $_item->getProduct();
$isVisibleProduct = $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
/** @var \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $helper */
$helper = $this->helper('Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data');
$canApplyMsrp = $helper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($product) && $helper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($product);
?>
<tbody class="cart item">
    <tr class="item-info">
        <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Item')); ?>" class="col item">
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl() ?>"
                   title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>"
                   tabindex="-1"
                   class="product-item-photo">
            <?php else:?>
                <span class="product-item-photo">
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php echo $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml(); ?>
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                </a>
            <?php else: ?>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="product-item-details">
                <strong class="product-item-name">
                    <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                        <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?></a>
                        <?php echo "Hellow World";?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>
                        <?php echo "Hellow World";?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </strong>
                <?php if ($_options = $block->getOptionList()):?>
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
                            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $block->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                            <dt><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                            <dd>
                                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </dd>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </dl>
                <?php endif;?>
                <?php if ($messages = $block->getMessages()): ?>
                    <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
                        <div class="cart item message <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $message['type'] ?>"><div><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?></div></div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
                <?php if ($addInfoBlock): ?>
                    <?php echo $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        </td>

        <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
            <td class="col msrp" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')); ?>">
                <span class="pricing msrp">
                    <span class="msrp notice"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('See price before order confirmation.'); ?></span>
                    <?php $helpLinkId = 'cart-msrp-help-' . $_item->getId(); ?>
                    <a href="#" class="action help map" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($helpLinkId); ?>" data-mage-init='{"addToCart":{"helpLinkId": "#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $helpLinkId;?>","productName": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $product->getName(); ?>","showAddToCart": false}}'>
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __("What's this?"); ?></span>
                    </a>
                </span>
            </td>
        <?php else: ?>
            <td class="col price" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')); ?>">
                <?php echo $block->getUnitPriceHtml($_item); ?>
            </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <td class="col qty" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>">
            <div class="field qty">
                <label class="label" for="cart-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>-qty">
                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span>
                </label>
                <div class="control qty">
                    <input id="cart-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>-qty"
                           name="cart[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"
                           data-cart-item-id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getSku() ?>"
                           value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getQty() ?>"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>"
                           class="input-text qty"
                           maxlength="12"
                           data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
                           data-role="cart-item-qty"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class="col subtotal" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal'));?>">
            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
                <span class="cart msrp subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $block->getRowTotalHtml($_item); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item-actions">
        <td colspan="100">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getActions($_item) ?>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Magento still gets its own template even after overriding.
I'm not able to override my default.phtml template by overriding the xml.

Comment: give name to block but different than core block name

Comment: @RonakChauhan which block are you suggesting to name?

Comment: `<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="XYZ_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml">` give name to this block

Comment: I gave name to that block but still not showing my template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override two core checkout xml file for override default.phtml file  in magento 2,

**app/code/XYZ/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.form">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override" as="renderer.list.custom"/>
            <arguments>
                <argument name="renderer_list_name" xsi:type="string">checkout.cart.item.renderers.override</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/XYZ/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override">

            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="XYZ_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml" />              

            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="XYZ_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml" />   

        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: It gives a runtime exception as below:
(RuntimeException): Renderer for type "simple" does not exist.

Comment: remove var folder

Comment: Hi Rakesh,
I cleared cache & deleted var folder but still same error.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, the above code is working now, but for bundle product or configurable product, their options are not being displayed, I checked the code and in the default.pthml file the code `<?php if ($_options = $block->getOptionList()):?>` returns false.

Comment: Its working but edit and delete icon can't show.

Comment: Hi Rekesh, it gave me a error. But after i removed the class in referenceBlock ( checkout_cart_index.xml ) it worked as expected.

Comment: Its working but edit and delete icon can't show