# Product Options not showing on Shopping Cart page for Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart

I did some customization as per the solution provided by **Rakesh** in following question
[Overriding template not working in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146423/overriding-template-not-working-in-magento-2)

I have got what I wanted as per the solution mentioned in above question but now the product options for bundle and configurable products are not showing.

**Before** **customization**, my **shopping cart** used to look like this.

[image]

**After customization**

[image]

How to get product options to show on Shopping Cart page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution

after adding following code in checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml

> /XYZ/Checkout/view/frontend/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml

```
<block class="Magento\Bundle\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="bundle" template="XYZ_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.bundle.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.bundle.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.bundle.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
            </block>

            <block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Configurable" as="configurable" template="XYZ_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
            </block>
```