# Magento 2 configurable product cart item override issue

Tags: magento-2.1

I have override two core checkout xml files for overriding default.phtml file in magento 2 as per the ref url -
[Overriding template not working in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146423/overriding-template-not-working-in-magento-2)

But when I add configurable product to my cart, then its global attributes like color and size are not visible on cart page.

> app/code/XYZ/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.form">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override" as="renderer.list.custom"/>
            <arguments>
                <argument name="renderer_list_name" xsi:type="string">checkout.cart.item.renderers.override</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/XYZ/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override">

            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="XYZ_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml" />              

            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="XYZ_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml" />   

        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if it's correct, but I had the same issue and this worked for me:

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override">
  <block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Configurable" as="configurable" template="XYZ_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions" as="actions">
      <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
      <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
    </block>
  </block>
  <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="XYZ_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml" />  
  <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="XYZ_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml" />  
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml

```
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Xyz_Abc::cart/item/default.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this overridden template in the layout XML file. It's only for configurable products.

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
        <block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Configurable" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable" as="configurable" template="YOURMODULE_CustomCart::cart/item/default.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions" as="actions">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions.edit" template="YOURMODULE_CustomCart::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions.remove" template="YOURMODULE_CustomCart::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

It's working for me 100% tested. If this help to you give upwards. 
Thank you.